# Learning C basics - Struct function:

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm currently trying to create a program from a struct function as I show below. Instead of printing a line directly from the program, I want to modify the program to print a message asking the user to input the information about a person and display it as the struct indicates.

Instead of doing "struct person p" and inserting the information, i want it to be inputed as a scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int day, month, year;
} DATA;
typedef struct person {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float salary;
    DATA birth;
} PERSON;

void Mostrar(struct person x){
    printf("name: %s\n",x.name);
    printf("age: %d\n",x.age);
    printf("Salário: %f\n",x.salary);
    printf("Dt.birth: %d/%d/%d\n",x.birth.day, x.birth.month, x.birth.year);
}

int main(){
    struct person p = {"Carlos", 23, 12345, {23,5,1954}};
    Mostrar(p);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You can use `scanf`.

Comment: What prevents you from using `scanf`??

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `scanf`

```
PERSON getPerson(void)
{
    PERSON person;
    if(!fgets(person.name, sizeof(person.name), stdin)) { /* error handling */} //you can also remove \n at the end if you need to
    if(scanf("%d %f", &person.age, &person.salary) != 2) { /* error handling */}
    if(scanf("%d %d %d", &person.birth.day, &person.birth.month, &person.birth.year) != 3) { /* error handling */}
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Actually the `\n` really should be removed, otherwise it will sooner or later cause trouble.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is in the comment. Removing \n is not in the scope of this question

Comment: No, it isn't but the OP will sooner or later stumble upon it.